# How to add FIWARE/OpenStack Keystone authentication to Meteor app?

Tags: javascript, meteor, openstack, fiware, meteor-accounts

We are researching how to integrate our Meteor application with an SSO provider based on OpenStack Keyrock. To the extent possible, we would like to align our efforts with the platform, to avoid maintaining a custom package.

How can we use FIWARE/OpenStack Keyrock to authenticate users in our Meteor application?

Comment: Do you want to know how to use Keyrock? I have a tutorial explaining the integration between Orion, Keyrock and Wilma. Maybe it can be useful for what you need: the basic steps with Keyrock.

Comment: A tutorial would be helpful. I am in the initial research phase to figure out how to integrate FIWARE Keyrock authentication into a JavaScript application (based on Meteor.js).